# svg place shape on path

Tags: path, svg, shapes, css-position

I am creating a game in SVG and require square tiles to be placed along a path, named a *road*.

The path can be curved or placed in an angle and I would like to rotate the square tiles relative to the path.

My current structure looks like this:

```
<defs>
    <rect id="tile" width="200" height="200" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"/>
</defs>
```

```
<g style="stroke-width=10px; stroke:#23238E;>
   <path id="road1" d="M100 100 L 500 100"/>
   <path id="road2" d="M500 100 L 200 100"/>
</g>
```

My current understanding of SVG tells me I will have to calculate the positions of the tiles through interpolation but can I rotate the tiles relative to the path in an automated fashion?

So how can I apply *`<use x="xx" y="yy" orient="`**auto**`" xlink:href="tile"/>`* ?

The roads are generated from the following information:

```
id = #
vector2D = {
  x1 = #
  y1 = #
  x2 = #
  y2 = #
}
tiles = # // number of tiles in road
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael http://raphaeljs.com provides the angle of a path at any point through `path.getPointAtLenght(x)`. SVG has a native implementation, but it doesn't provide the angle. You could look into Raphael's source to see what's going on. Here is the relevant bit:

```
getLengthFactory = function (istotal, subpath) {
        return function (path, length, onlystart) {
            path = path2curve(path);
            var x, y, p, l, sp = "", subpaths = {}, point,
                len = 0;
            for (var i = 0, ii = path.length; i < ii; i++) {
                p = path[i];
                if (p[0] == "M") {
                    x = +p[1];
                    y = +p[2];
                } else {
                    l = getPointAtSegmentLength(x, y, p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6]);
                    if (len + l > length) {
                        if (subpath && !subpaths.start) {
                            point = getPointAtSegmentLength(x, y, p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], length - len);
                            sp += ["C" + point.start.x, point.start.y, point.m.x, point.m.y, point.x, point.y];
                            if (onlystart) {return sp;}
                            subpaths.start = sp;
                            sp = ["M" + point.x, point.y + "C" + point.n.x, point.n.y, point.end.x, point.end.y, p[5], p[6]].join();
                            len += l;
                            x = +p[5];
                            y = +p[6];
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!istotal && !subpath) {
                            point = getPointAtSegmentLength(x, y, p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], length - len);
                            return {x: point.x, y: point.y, alpha: point.alpha};
                        }
                    }
                    len += l;
                    x = +p[5];
                    y = +p[6];
                }
                sp += p.shift() + p;
            }
            subpaths.end = sp;
            point = istotal ? len : subpath ? subpaths : R.findDotsAtSegment(x, y, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], 1);
            point.alpha && (point = {x: point.x, y: point.y, alpha: point.alpha});
            return point;
        };
```

Where point.alpha is the rotation angle.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be looking into using markers for the tiles and then splitting up the path so that you have vertices where you want the rects to appear as marker-mid points. You'd get orientation for free with markers.

Comment: But as I understand it you cannot link events or listeners to markers as they are not really part of the DOM/structure but more of the presentation side of things.
That's what I remember from the last time I was experimenting with SVG

Comment: Your question does not mention that requirement.